# Replacing math.random() with array in AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, math, random

A very quick question. I am working with some flash banners to Google Network, which don't allow math.random(). Are there any way to replace this with a custom array, that mimics randomness, e.g.

> var MyArray:Array = [3,6,4,3,6,7,4,6,3,3,5].

Basically I just need to know how to replace math.random with a number from the array in the statements like the following. It's not a problem if the numbers are pulled sequentially.

```
function myFunction():void {
    myVariable = myVariableTwo + Math.random()*myVariableThree;
}
```

Do I need to loop through the array and extract numbers, and if so how so?

I'm still fumbling my way around in AS3, so don't be afraid to explain it like you are speaking to a child.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: make an Array with manually added numbers, for example [2,4,9,0,8,4,3,4,1,1,1,0]. you should know beforehand how many times you'll need numbers from this array. then, if you need a number, call myArray.shift(). this will give you the first child of the array, while also removing it from the array. so in the first run with your example array, after shift(), we would have [4,9,0,8...etc]. you could also store the value you shifted from the array, use it, and then put it on the top of array again with myArray.push(some value)

Comment: @DodgerThud Thanks a lot for your interest and help to solve the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a [random seed algorithm](http://blog.stroep.nl/2012/07/random-seed-actionscript/) to produce random-like behaviour from a function call without using Math.random, however since they don't like you using `Math.random` they might not like you essentially emulating it's behaviour in a different form.

The alternative would be to just have a fixed array of results accompanied with a function which returns the first element of the array and pushes back on the end to be reused:

```
package Rnd
{
    public class Rnd
    {
        private static var VALUES:Array = [ 1, 5, 4, 5, 3, 8, 3, 2, 1, 1, 6, 9 ];

        public static function getValue():uint
        {
            var val:uint = Rnd.VALUES.shift();
            Rnd.VALUES.push(val);
            return val;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Right on the spot! Thanks a bunch!